# In django user model , i want to add contact ,username and role fields

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created AbstractBaseUser in my Models.py , and i am able to create email,password,first_name and Last_name.
I want contact,username and Role as well in the same User Model.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Have you read Django documentation? I think there's all what you need.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user